# Project Euler #5 Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is the problem:

> 2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder.
>   What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

Here is my code:

```
var calculation = function(){
        var result = 0;
        for(var i = 20; i == 10000000000000; i++){
                for(var e = 2; e == 20; e++){
                        if(i % e == 0){
                                result = i;
                        }
                }
        }
        alert(result);      
}
calculation();
```

The problem is that the program just outputs `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are more graceful ways to solve this problem, but to address your current issue, the 'condition' portion of the `for`-loop needs to return `true` when you want to continue the loop, not when you want to stop it. So your `for` loops should look like this:

```
for(var i = 20; i <= 10000000000000; i++){
    for(var e = 2; e <= 20; e++){
        ...
    }
}
```

Inside the loops, you've got another issue. You're setting `result` if `i % e == 0` but you've never defined a stop-case. In other words `result` will be the last number you which passed that test, even if it failed all the other tests for `i` and `e`. You'd have to do something like this:

```
for(var i = 20; i <= 10000000000000; i++){
    bool found = true;
    for(var e = 2; e <= 20; e++){
        if (i % e != 0) {
            found = false;
            break; // stop testing other divisors
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if there was a better way to do the loop. Should I use a while loop withe the for loop inside?

Comment: @user2406223 *Hint:* a better solution would be to start with a small number, say `2`, and build up to your solution from there. Note that all numbers divisible by 2 to n, are also divisible by 2 to n-1.

Comment: Two can't be the solution. It has to be higher than 20.

Comment: @user2406223 What I mean is, you don't have to simply loop through all integers between `2` and `1e13`. Start with a small numer, `i=2`, then for each number `n`, up to 20, find the next number that's divisible by `i` and `n`.

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
        for(var i = 20; i == 10000000000000; i++){
```

the `i == 10000000000000` bit means that the loop should only run as long as `i` is equal to `10000000000000` — which it never is, since it's already not that to begin with.

I imagine you meant to write `i <= 10000000000000`.

(There are other problems with your code as well — I recommend using a much smaller number for debugging, so you can figure them out without crashing your browser — but that should get you started.)

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER should be the largest possible number.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Answer (score 0):

// Kindly check this below JS program.

```js
var count=0,num=1;

while(count<20){
    for(var i=1;i<=20;i++){
        if(num % i==0){
            count++;
        }
        else{
            count=0;
            break;
        }
    }
  if(count==20){
    console.log(num);
    break;
  }
else
  {
    num++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah firstly, pick a language that you are comfortable in for solving these problems. I'm pretty sure that in every single language out there a for loop condition `==` doesnt mean less than or equal to so perhaps study up on fundamentals of any programming language first.

Secondly assuming that you put in the `<=` in your for loop, your inner for loop logic is flawed. If you are new, then the most logical way to do this would be to write something to the effect of this:

```
if (i%2==0 && i%3==0 && i%4 == 0 && ... && i%20==0)
  alert(i);`
```

One way to achieve this is to use the help of a boolean and you can do something like this:

```
for (var i=20; i<=1000000000; i++) { //Your upper bound is wayy too high.
  var done = true;
  for (var e = 2; done && e <= 20; e++) { //Be more efficient.
    done = done && (i % e == 0);
  }
  if (done) {
    alert(i);
    return;
  }
}
```